# Having trouble understanding roles in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am having trouble understanding what a role truly is in AWS. Maybe I am just overthinking this.

So as I am reading a role in AWS is a more "secure" solution in AWS to that of a group as it is temporary where as group access is permanent. What is temporary about a role? Does it timeout?

Also - alot of explanations coin roles as what you would use when any service in AWS needs to talk to another service (For example my EC2 instance needs to talk to my S3 bucket). This is confusing to me because alot of documentation conflicts this and says roles are the end all be all of security and that any users should be granted access through roles.

What am I misunderstanding here?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's really about IAM User credentials (which are long-lived) vs. STS credentials (which are time-limited). The latter are considered a best practice because, if leaked, there is a limited window in which they are usable.

Answer (score 0):

Roles have sessions that expire. Once they expire, you need to sign-in or re-assume the role. More on this can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use.html

Specifically, look at the table column `Credential Lifetime` and the footnote #2. That is how the role assumption is temporary and provides accounts/services with temporary access.

And yes, roles are used when doing communication between AWS services, like an EC2 retrieving an object from an S3 bucket. Users can also assume roles when doing things. For instance, you can assume a role when "signing in" to the AWS console. A good use case would be you if your company has Active Directory setup, so you sign in via that, then you can choose a role to assume. This way your identity is federated through your company but you never actually provide a username or password to AWS, like you would have to if you were to sign in using a user.

Check out here for a rundown on roles in general: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id.html#id_iam-roles